# How to make a count-up with input date

Tags: javascript

So, I learned how to do a countdown timer, I finally got it, and now I tried to make the opposite by myself, a count up timer. Basically, I created a new date and it increments to the infinite. But, this time I want that date to be introduced by the user, and not set by me in the code.

If possible, please use vanilla JS since I don't know any frameworks.

PS: Can you also explain me how that variables get the hours/minutes/etc. ? I don't understand how that Math.floor operations get the job done.

```js
let startingDate = new Date('September 14, 2020 17:04').getTime();
let counter = document.querySelector('.countup-timer');

setInterval(function() {
    let newDate = new Date().getTime();
    let finalDate = newDate - startingDate;

    let days = Math.floor(finalDate / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((finalDate % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((finalDate % (1000 * 60 *60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((finalDate % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    counter.innerHTML = days+"d"+hours+"h"+minutes+"m"+seconds+"s";
}, 1000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Count up</title>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <p class="countup-timer"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="countdown_v2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"Can you also explain me how that variables get the hours/minutes/etc. ? I don't understand how that Math.floor operations get the job done."* lets say you have 90 seconds. You know that one minute has 60 seconds. `90/60 = 1.5`. `Math.floor(1.5) = 1`. I.e. 90 seconds contains 1 full minute.

Comment: Parsing text as dates is something that vanilla JavaScript isn't very good at. Do you want to allow the use to specify a date as free form text? Or are you going to provide separate input elements for year, month, day, hour, etc ?

Comment: I think the first choice. And about the Math.floor(), in my example I'm using miliseconds (because of setInterval() ) and that really misguides me.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("local_time").addEventListener('change', timechanged);
function timechanged(){
let startingDate = new Date(this.value).getTime();
let counter = document.querySelector('.countup-timer');

setInterval(function() {
    let newDate = new Date().getTime();
    let finalDate = newDate - startingDate;

    let days = Math.floor(finalDate / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours = Math.floor((finalDate % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((finalDate % (1000 * 60 *60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((finalDate % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    counter.innerHTML = days+"d"+hours+"h"+minutes+"m"+seconds+"s";
}, 1000) 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Count up</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <input type="datetime-local" id="local_time">
    <p class="countup-timer"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

you can do something like this, let allow the user to enter the date, and take that in your code and start the timer

**how that Math.floor**

The floor() method rounds a number DOWNWARDS to the nearest integer and returns the result.

Comment: I ran your code snippet, and entered a date. But it doesn't work correctly, looks buggy. Anyway, thank you for answering.

Comment: hi @MariusC. that's my pleasure, can you please let me know what bug you found

Comment: It counts, but, in a split second it shows NaN, some negative value and after that counts, and now I ran it again and it counts, but again, for a split second the minutes toggle to 24 and set back to 0.

Comment: oops my bad, I'm sorry for that, will look about this.